# Load remote URL from phonegap1.2

Tags: ios, html, cordova, ios5

I am quite new to PhoneGap, currently its version is 1.2. With the default template created,it will go to local www/index.html, my idea is to let it load remote URL for example http://mydomain.com , I think it could be very simple, but not for me right now. Anyone could give such guidance ?

There is one [here](http://www.joeldare.com/wiki/open_a_url_in_phonegap), but it was out dated now. 
Thanks

Comment: note that such apps will not be accepted by the iOS app store...

Comment: thanks at first, could you give me more about WHY ?

Comment: since the AppStore rules don't allow downloading the whole app as dynamic content from the web - they want the HTML to be local, and only data to be retrieved from the web (otherwise why would you use a NativeApp and not just a WebApp?)

Comment: check the review guidelines from Apple https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html  is this one "Apps that are not very useful, are simply web sites bundled as apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected" ? But we can add more native features instead of only invoking remote URL , that is why we still need figure out how to load remote URL from phonegap.

Comment: I've actually successfully loaded other URLs instead of www/index.html, what's your code exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You should use local **index.html** at start. But you can create an **iframe** in **index.html**. Then you can add cross-domain support and send **$.postMessage()** using **jQuery** to get phonegap functionality on remote URL.